# Why app screenshots are in random order on App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I uploaded 10 screenshots on iTunesConnect but after approval of the app, order of these 10 screenshots is random on every device. It is not same in the order as these uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it's solved now. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666391

Comment: Now order is fine after some days without any action.